# PHP REST API Server send multiple data to client

Tags: php, django, api, rest, websocket

I have PHP REST API Server. My client is written in python, client only sends request to my server and sometimes uploading file etc.

My php script calling 9 functions. Each function changes string. I want to send this changed string to my client (python) after each function.
Like in php file;

```
$result = func1(); // it takes 5 seconds for example
echo $result;
$result = func2(); // it takes 5 seconds for example
echo $result;
...
```

But it only shows result when php script finished. I want to show it when each function returned data.

I tried **flush**, **ob_flush** but it **didn't work** I think because of has not GUI (REST API).
Maybe should I use django? Or better ways?
I hope it was understandable, Thanks!

Comment: ob_flush() is the right way. You need to put after each echo.

Comment: @MarkusZeller It doesn't work with postman application. It only works on webbrowser.

Comment: Then postman seems to do some chunk caching.